# JSON variable undefined when global

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, global

I want to make a variable "**city**" global and use it in other  function. I am requesting a JSON data and it seems to work in this function

```
var city;

function conditions(data) {
        var city = data.current_observation.display_location.full;
        var wcode = data.current_observation.icon;

        $('#city').append('<h2>' +'Weather forecast in ' + city + '</h2>');
        $('#city').addClass('headings-style');

    }
```

But whe I try to use variable **city** in other function I'm getting an undefined data:

```
function forecastDays(info) {
        var locationOne = info.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday;
        locationOne.forEach(function (daysPlus) {

        var high = daysPlus.high.celsius;
        var low = daysPlus.low.celsius;
        var arr = ["day1", "day2", "day3", "day4"];
        jQuery.each(arr, function (i, val) {

            $("#temp_" + val).html('<p>' + city + 'High: ' + high + '&deg;C' + '<br>' + ' Low: ' + low + '&deg;C' + '</p>');

            });
        });
```

Please, help.

Comment: You re-declare `city` inside `conditions`. Do `city = ...` instead of `var city = ...`.

Comment: A good question! It is a mistake that is often made and therefore it is good that attention is paid to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
var city = data.current_observation.display_location.full;
```

you should do

```
city = data.current_observation.display_location.full;
```

in order to set the value of the global `city` variable. Re-using `var` keyword will declare a new variable `city` in function scope, rather than global.

Answer (score 1):

Little, late, but here's an example. *(@J. Chen provided the answer)*

When you use `var city =` you're redefining the variable within the function scope, so it' no longer accessible from the global scope.

In the example below, the `city` variable is being used correctly in the global scope, where the `town` variable is being redefined in the function scope:

```js
var city;
var town;

function foo() {
  city = "New York";
  var town = "Boston";
};

function bar() {
  console.log(city);
  console.log(town);
}

foo(); // assigns the variable a value
bar(); // console "New York" / undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

delete var `city` in `funtion conditions`